# finding a variable from string input and extracting it with regex c#

Tags: c#, regex

~I have a client which is sending the a message to my server and I am trying to get substrings in order to extract them into variables. I want to use regex for this. Although I have no syntax problems, it will not match. This is the message I am sending and my code.

" PUT /John\r\n\r\n
London "

```
private StreamReader sReader = null;
private StreamWriter sWriter = null;


public SocketClass(Socket s)
    {
        socket = s;
        NetworkStream nStream = new NetworkStream(s);
        sReader = new StreamReader(nStream);
        sWriter = new StreamWriter(nStream);
        startSocket();
    }
String txt = "";
        while (sReader.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            txt += sReader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";
        }

        else if (txt.Contains("PUT"))
        {

            Console.WriteLine("triggered");
            Regex pattern = new Regex(@"PUT /(?<Name>\d+)\r\n\r\n(?<Location>\d+)\r\n");
            Match match = pattern.Match(txt);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                String Name = match.Groups["Name"].Value;
                String Location = match.Groups["Location"].Value;
                Console.WriteLine(Name);
                Console.WriteLine(Location);

            }
        }
```

Comment: If you want to match newline/CR characters, pass `RegexOptions.SingleLine` as a parameter to the Regex constructor.

Comment: I have added the parameter but it still does not match

Comment: You need to prefix some characters. Like the `/` to `//`

Comment: Your input string does not have (a) `\r\n` at the end and (b) will not match against `\d+` which means *one or more **digits***.

Comment: Can you show how you are getting the `txt` variable? The message you are sending seems to be showing the HTTP command (`PUT /name`) and then empty lines followed by the body of the request (`Location`). I'd be surprised if you were getting both of those in the same parameter...

Comment: You input string has spaces between LF and CR chars that aren't matched in the regex. This question is bogus.

Comment: @spender: How does that make it bogus? People ask questions here because their code doesn't work. Finding a mistake in the code surely doesn't make the question less valid?

Comment: @Chris because the input string provided doesn't correlate to anything near what's in the Regex and there's no statement of intent about what OP expects to happen. That means that we are left guessing about the OPs intent. This looks like a straightforward "I want to parse HTTP headers with regex" question, but I wouldn't want to guess, so all I can do is point out inconsistencies in the question without committing to an answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding in the source of txt but it doesn't really help explain where it comes from (now I want to know what the `sReader` is). Perhaps the better question though would be what is the value of txt when you are in that `else if`?

Comment: @Jeroen van Langen I have tried prefixing the character / with an extra / which didnt help.

Comment: @Chris I need to find whats supposed to be name and location from the txt variable and define them. The line of string which is in the txt contains both of them.

Comment: @spender: I'm not disagreeing about it being a bad question, but saying it is bogus is saying it is fake or not genuine. ie that the OP doesn't really have a problem at all and is trying to deceive us in some way which is what confused me.

Comment: @spender I am actually trying find name and location from txt and define them

Comment: @denz Are you trying to parse HTTP headers? It seems yes, but the input string of your question ***isn't a valid HTTP header***.

Comment: @spender: Its not http headers. Its a full(ish) http request I believe. The headers and body would be separated by two line breaks (not sure if it is valid to have whitespace between those two line breaks). So it looks like it is the HTTP request (ie `PUT /name`) no other headers and then the body which just says `Location`. I assume the `sReader` is reading from the socket and just reading the entire request like that. @denz: is this correct?

Comment: @spender the string of my question is actually HTTP/0.9 and the specific string is what I need to work with in this specific case

Comment: @denz, so is the space between CRLF in your input string a typo? `\r\n \r\n`?

Comment: @chris What you are saying is correct and I updated the code further. Yes i am sorry I have just realized. It is a typo.

Comment: Another question. are name and location actually numbers in what you receive rather than text? At the moment your question suggests that you have literally `PUT /name` but your regex suggests you are expecting numbers. Not clear on whether this is a problem with your regex or a problem with your description of the input. If appropriate please put an *actual* value that txt has when you are trying to parse it.

Comment: @chris It is a problem with my regex. I didnt know my current code was for numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that while your input has alphanumeric characters your regex is looking for `\d` which are numeric digits. The regex can be easily changed to this to make it work:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"PUT /(?<Name>.+)\r\n\r\n(?<Location>.+)\r\n");
```

`.` represents any character. It may be that you could narrow it down more to say the match has to be alphabetic characters or something else but the above will certainly work for your given input.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I firstly tried to replace the whole line with PUT /(?.+)\r\n\r\n(?.+)\r\n but this threw me an exception. Then I tried to replace the "d"s with "."s which fixed the exception but it still wouldnt match

Comment: I actually fixed it. Thank you so much !!